# Posting photo on Facebook with tags using Koala

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, koala

I'm trying to post a photo using Koela using the following code but its not taging the users

```
@graph.put_picture(pic_url,{:message => msg,:tags => [{:id => "xxxxxxx"} ,{:id=>"xxxxxxx"}]})
```

Here's the facebook link buts its in PHP
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no put_tag function in Koala so you have to use the more generic put_connections function:

```
@graph.put_connections(you_image_id, 'tags', {"to" => uid})
```

https://github.com/arsduo/koala/blob/master/lib/koala/api/graph_api.rb#L144

Answer (score 0):

this is the documentation for put_picture
but i dont see it able to tag...u can take a look ,and i think tere is an x and y coordinates have to be passed in order to tag in the picture.

https://github.com/arsduo/koala/blob/master/lib/koala/api/graph_api.rb

Comment: X and y are not required. They are optional