# Facebook - Tag user in photo, keep getting OAuthException - Unknown Error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm making a Facebook app in Rails using Koala gem.

My app needs to **upload** a picture to a Page's Album and **tag** the User who submitted it.

I keep getting this error when I want to tag the photo:

```
Koala::Facebook::ServerError in PhotosController#update
type: OAuthException, code: 1, message: An unknown error has occurred. [HTTP 500]
```

My app already have `publish_actions` permission set, so it's not permission issue.

Here's my code:

```
# token, photo_id, and user_id is confirmed to be not the problem

@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(token)
@graph.put_connections(photo_id, "tags",
  {
    tag_uid: user_id
  }
)
```

If I'm using User's Token, the photo is tagged successfully but still goes to that Error page. If with Page's Token, nothing is tagged and goes to Error.

Any hint or solution?

Thanks

Comment: which kind of token do you use ? to get this kind of informations you need to use a token from an user login with the right scope

Comment: I tried both User and Page token. I get the  user token from JavaScript SDK, then convert it to Page's token. According documentation, I need `publish_actions` permission to tag a user, which I already use.

Comment: I got the same error with bad token, try to debug yours : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#debug

Answer (score 0):

My solution to upload photo:

```
def post_to_facebook
  conf = YAML.load_file File.join(Rails.root,'public','fb.yaml')
  oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(conf['app'], conf['key'], "http://yoursite.com/social_networks/callback_facebook?id=#{params[:id]}")
  redirect_to oauth.url_for_oauth_code(:permissions => 'publish_stream,photo_upload,manage_pages')
end

def callback_facebook
  news = News.find(params[:id])
  conf = YAML.load_file File.join(Rails.root,'public','fb.yaml')
  oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(conf['app'], conf['key'], "http://yoursite.com/social_networks/callback_facebook?id=#{params[:id]}")
  token = oauth.get_access_token(params[:code])
  page = FbGraph::Page.new(page_id).fetch(:access_token => token, :fields => :access_token)
  mes = "text_mes"
  img_url = "http://yoursite.com#{news.news_image_url}"
  page.photo!(:message => mes, :url => img_url)

  redirect_to 'https://www.facebook.com/your_page'
end
```

Where page_id is id of facebook's page where photo will be upload

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer and sorry that I forgot to mention in the Question that my uploading part works fine. Only the tagging part keeps getting error. Any idea about tagging?

Comment: I find some info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14857516/3327850), but i think you had saw this already

Answer (score 0):

I have found two possible reasons:

1. The fact that Facebook doesn't allow us to tag non-friend. Since my token is Page's token, it doesn't have friend.
2. Maybe Page can't tag anyone.

Even if the user "Liked" the page, it doesn't allow to be tagged.

I changed the token to a User's token and the tagging works fine (as long as it tags a friend of that User).

I will leave this question open for anyone to add proper answer.